# Which language allow me to change the value of a parameter of a function?

Tags: arduino, programming-languages

And, is the language of Arduino one of them?
I am really curious about this ;)

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you're asking here, but in nearly every language you can change or define function parameters.

I would also recommend taking a beginning programming course, as this would teach you the basics of such principles.

Answer (score 0):

The code you use in the Arduino IDE is mostly C++ with a bit C, so yes you can change the value of a parameter or function.
And you should really read some programming principles first, before you even touch on the Arduino, like @WillLangas said.